# Задать условие для вывода информации

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Имеется таблица `friends_fan` , её структура:

```
id     - AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_us  - id пользователя,
id_kto - id подписчика,
fan    - подписан ли пользователь (1: да, 0: нет)
```

**Задача**: если пользователь уже подписан на пользователя ( а пользователь определяется переменной `us_p['id']` ), то вывести текст "Отписаться". Если же не подписан - вывести "Подписаться".

При подписке в таблице создается две ячейки, где данные `id_us` и `id_kto` чередуются.

Вот мой вариант кода:

```
$VZfA = mysql_fetch_assoc(
    mysql_query(
        "SELECT * FROM `friends_fan` WHERE `id_us` = '$us[users_id]' AND `fan` = '1' LIMIT 1"
    )
);

if ($VZfA['id_kto'] != $us_p['id']){
    echo "<a class='button' href='/friends_add.go?act=fan_del&id=$USPInfo[users_id]'>Отписатся</a>";
}else{
    echo "<a class='button' href='/friends_add.go?id=$USPInfo[users_id]'>Подписаться</a>";
}
```

Но он не правильно работает

Comment: А что не работает ? запрос или условие?

Comment: В запросе `$us[users_id]`, а в проверке `$us_p['id']`. Здесь не подразуменвается одна и таже переменная?

Comment: эти две переменные = если пользователь находиться у себя на страничке

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

```
 $VZfA = mysql_fetch_assoc(
    mysql_query(
        "SELECT * FROM `friends_fan` WHERE `id_us` = ".$us[users_id]." AND `id_kto` = ".$us_p['id']."  LIMIT 1"
    )
);

if ($VZfA['fan'] == 1 ){
    echo "<a class='button' href='/friends_add.go?act=fan_del&id=".$USPInfo[users_id].">Отписатся</a>";
}else{
    echo "<a class='button' href='/friends_add.go?id=".$USPInfo[users_id].">Подписаться</a>";
}
```

Возможны синтаксические ошибки, но идея должна быть понятна.